# Can't connect to port 8080 osx

Tags: networking, macos

We have a development server setup in port 8080, which has been working fine until this morning when it suddenly decided to stop working. This is happening in two machines with different versions of OS X (10.11.3 (15D21) and 10.10.5 (14F1605)).

I have turned off the firewall (ESET) and tried a few commands to try to debug what is going on, but I can't figure out what is happening.

Using the server we are using for development ([gulp connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect)), if I run

`sudo lsof -n -P | grep :8080`

it says that node is using the server. Connecting via telnet and trying to get something results in it hanging until it closes the connection:

[image]

Running lsof with pythons's SimpleHTTPServer results in something similar:

```
Python    4252        uorbe001    3u     IPv4 0x20afecd27e29e697        0t0      TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

But telnet simply closes the connection:

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Changing the port to any other random port (have tried 8081, and a few 90xx) makes it work, but for some reason it doesn't like 8080 anymore.

As I said earlier, this started happening suddenly in two different machines with different versions of OS X, but I can't figure out what could possibly be happening.

Does anyone know how to debug this?

Comment: You have restarted OSX machines, right? And you have not installed any services/programs recently on those machines? Sounds just a conflict with the port. Some other service/program maybe also is using the port or at least trying to..

Comment: Yes, we have restarted both machines a couple of times, and haven't installed anything on them recently (one of them updated osx this morning, but the other one was on an ancient version of it before finding the issue)

Comment: there is also no errors when SimpleHttpServer and gulp-connect start, which you'd usually get if there's something bound to that port already.

Comment: Are the telnet versions same on the machine's that work and that do not work?

Comment: the telnet tests I did were on the same machine, they are just acting different depending on the server used.